# Indexing array with an array of keys Shorthand in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, functional-programming, indexing

Often I find myself with an array of keys to some other array and want to get the corresponding values. For example if I wanted to select a random subarray, the function  `array_rand($array)` will return an array of random indices and I want to get the values.  There are many examples other than this but the general problem (normally arising from functional programming style) is I have an array of keys and need the array of the corresponding values. Here is a wordy way of doing this but I was wondering if there were some shorter way to do this frequent task?

**way 1:**

```
$array_of_values = array();
foreach($array_of_indices as $index)
    $array_of_values[] = $array_of_data[$index];
```

**way 2:**

```
function index_array($index) { return $array_of_data[$index]; }
$array_of_values = array_map("index_array", $array_of_indices);
```

**way 3:**

```
$array_of_values = array_intersect_key($array_of_data,
                   array_fill_keys($array_of_indices, ''));
```

I would expect that some single function to do this exists but after reading through the docs I couldn't find one. Anyone know a better way?

Comment: He wants to combine keys from a one array with values from another array, so array_values() won't fit here.

Comment: Myself, I prefer way 1. It makes it clear what the goal of the code is without over complicating matters. I am pretty sure that there is not a single function to do what you want done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function that will do this on its own, however there is a slightly simpler way than **way 3**

```
array_intersect_key($array_of_data, array_flip($array_of_keys));
```